# how to delete an item from a lazy column in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I built a lazy column that gets it`s data from ViewModel and every time I add an item the lazy column recomposes and the new Item is being viewed in the lazy column, **But when I added the functionality of deleting an Item** the lazy column does not recompose and the removed item stays on the screen until a configuration change happens (Like rotating the screen).

**My question is how to make the lazy column know that the list has been updated after each Delete operation.**

here is the ViewModel:

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.shoppinglistcompose.entities.Item

class AddNewShoppingListViewModel : ViewModel() {

val items = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>(mutableListOf())

fun addNewItem(newItem: Item) {
    items.value = items.value?.plus(listOf(newItem)) as MutableList<Item>?
}

fun removeItem(item: Item) {
    items.value!!.remove(item)
    items.value = items.value?.plus(listOf()) as MutableList<Item>?
}
}
```

,The Compsable that shows the Lazy Column:

```
content = { paddingValues ->
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = text,
                onValueChange = { textFieldsViewModel.onShoppingListNameChanged(it) },
                label = { Text(text = "Shopping list Name") },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(start = 30.dp, end = 30.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
            )
            if (!items.value?.isEmpty()!!) {
                LazyColumn(
                    Modifier
                        .animateContentSize()
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(paddingValues)
                ) {
                    items(items = items.value!!) {
                        SingleItem(item = it) {
                            addNewShoppingListViewModel.removeItem(it)
                        }
                    }
                }

            } else {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "There are no shopping Items",
                        color = Color.Red,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5
                    )
                }
            }
        }
        if (showDialog.value) {
            MyDialog(
                showDialog = showDialog,
                textFieldsViewModel = textFieldsViewModel,
            ) {
                val name = textFieldsViewModel.shoppingItemText.value
                val quantity = textFieldsViewModel.itemQuantityText.value
                val item = Item(0, name!!, quantity!!.toInt(), 0)
                addNewShoppingListViewModel.addNewItem(item)
                textFieldsViewModel.shoppingItemText.value = ""
                textFieldsViewModel.itemQuantityText.value = ""
                showDialog.value = !showDialog.value
            }
        }

    },
```

And here is the Composable fun of the Item it self:

```
@Composable
fun SingleItem(item: Item, deleteClick: () -> Unit) {
val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val new: MutableState<Boolean> = remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
val color = remember { Animatable(Color(0xFFB9F6CA)) }
LaunchedEffect(new.value) {
    color.animateTo(if (new.value) Color(0xFFB9F6CA) else Color(0xFFE0F2F1))
}
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(4.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
    backgroundColor = color.value,
    elevation = 3.dp
) {
    composableScope.launch {
        delay(2000)
        new.value = false
    }
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth() , horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
            Text(text = item.name, style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5)
            Text(text = "${item.quantity}", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6)
        }
        IconButton(onClick = deleteClick) {
            Icon(Icons.Rounded.Delete, "Button for deleting an Item of the items list.")
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Contribution tip: for your next question, try to only include enough of the code to reproduce the problem or explain the question. The question above contains a lot of information not relevant to the issue you were having and makes the question more difficult to answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try replacing the line,

```
items.value!!.remove(item)
items.value = items.value?.plus(listOf()) as MutableList<Item>?
```

with,

```
items.value = items.value?.filter { it != item }?.toMutableList()
```

The problem is that the expression `items.value?.plus(listOf())` does not produce a different instance and the `ViewModel` doesn't republish the value because it is `==` to the previous value. This is because Kotlin will only allocate a new list if one of the operants of a list expression not equivalent to the result.

The use of `filter` above ensures that a new list is produce if `item` is in the list.

Comment: I found that deleting items from the list caused exceptions to be thrown: 
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76646004/compose-sorted-list-items-disappear-and-reappear

Comment: Please report the crash as a bug to https://goo.gle/compose-feedback with an example that reproduces it.